# Jquery UI tabs and MVC Client side validation on each tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-tabs, client-side-validation

I have 3 Jquery UI tabs on an MVC page which have NEXT/PREVIOUS functionality to move back and forth from one tab to other.

The challenge I am facing I wish to put client-side validation on each tab before user could move from one tab to other. Effectively, NEXT button on each tab should behave for SUBMIT-form(fields on that tab) functionality and Client side validation as well.

I have seen this: [ASP.Net MVC 3 client side validation with a 3 tabs form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175723/asp-net-mvc-3-client-side-validation-with-a-3-tabs-form)

BUT I want the design the page in a way to be flexible enough to  ACCOMMODATE CHANGES IN TERMS OF FIELDS ON EACH TAB, OR, ADDING MORE TABS on the page later.
Is there any way for some good approach from this perspective.

Comment: Traditionally, you would not have "Next/Previous" on tabs, tabs are supposed to be non-linear. You're describing a Wizard.

Comment: You can call it a mix of both. 
As I will be saving the data once NEXT is pressed on each tab if Client Side Validation goes a success(unlike a wizard). User can come next day to fill up second tab.

Comment: Still sounds like a wizard to me, just with resuming. I'm not sure jQuery tabs is what you're looking for here.

Comment: May be. I need an approach to perform the SUBMIT+ClientSideValidation functionality on NEXT button on each tabbed view. User should not be able to move to the next tab until the data is validated and thus submitted on the current tab using NEXT button.

Comment: @Darin or anybody can help me with this?